# How to add a logout to my React navbar with JWT?

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I am quite new to react and JavaScript. I am trying to make a dynamic navigation bar that shows certain links if the user is logged in or logged out. I want to base it off of if the JWT token is present or not. I am stuck on how to implement 'checking if a user is logged in using tokens' into my Navbar function, so the boolean works to use one component if public or one component if logged in.

```js
import "./navbar.css"
import NavLoggedIn from "./navLoggedIn"
import NavPublic from "./navPublic"

const Navbar = () => {
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
  
  return (
    <>
      { token === null ? <NavPublic /> : <NavLoggedIn /> }  
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```js
import "./navbar.css"


const NavLoggedIn = () => {
 
  return (
    <>
       <nav className="nav">
      <a href="/" className="site-title">Acebook</a>
        <li>
          <a href="/">profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/posts">posts</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="/login">logout</a>
        </li>
    </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default NavLoggedIn ;
```

```js
import "./navbar.css"

const NavPublic = () => {
 
  return (
    <>
       <nav className="nav">
        <a href="/" className="site-title">Acebook</a>
        <ul>
            
          <li>
            <a href="/signup">signup</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="/login">login</a>
          </li>      
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default NavPublic;
```

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on? Is your current solution not working or are you trying to figure out how to do this with a single Nav component?

Comment: my current solution isn't working. I was wondering what the best practice would be for it. As when the user is not logged in, it still shows the navbar logged in component rather than the navbar public(logged out) component. The part that determines if they're logged in is the token

Comment: Oh right. So the NavBar component only checks the token when it mounts. It's not "aware" of any changes to the authentication status that occur subsequently. In the projects I've worked on, I've typically used Redux. I've typically dispatched an action on login or logout to update the authentication status in a Redux. I would then check this in the NavBar with the `useSelector()` hook. If you're not using Redux you could do something similar with the context API. I can show you how to do that if you like.

Comment: yes please Neil that would be amazing. I am not using redux

Comment: I left an answer. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with the current approach is that the `NavBar` component only checks the token in `localStorage` when it mounts. It's "unaware" of subsequent changes to the authentication status.

I propose an alternative solution in which we use the Context API. We can start by introducing a new component:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

const AuthenticationContext = createContext({})

const AuthenticationProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  return (
    <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={{isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn}}>
      {children}
    </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthenticationProvider
```

This component has a named export, which exports a context and a default export which exports the provider. We can wrap the entire app in the provider. Assuming the root component is called `<App/>` , we can do this:

```
<AuthenticationProvider>
    <App/>
</AuthenticationProvider>
```

Now, in any component in your app that you can access this context like so:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { AuthenticationContext } from 'path/to/AuthenticationProvider'

const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthenticationContext)
```

In your login function you would call `setIsLoggedIn(true)` and in your logout function you would call  `setIsLoggedIn(false)`. Within your `NavBar` component you would check the value of `isLoggedIn`. The `NavBar` component should "see" whenever the value changes and render the correct Nav component.

Comment: Thank you Neil for taking the time to answer, this makes so much more sense and has it made it easier to understand

Comment: @jennifercodes glad I could help! Wen you have a moment, please click the checkbox next to the answer if it indeed fixed your problem.